# How to show a custom attribute in the admin Shipping Address box?

Tags: magento2, checkout, module, shipping-address

I have added the drop-down custom field on the checkout page with custom values. It's working fine also save attribute values in the database but not display in the order shipping address. Any idea how to show it?

[image]

**InstallSchema.php**

```
$connection->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('quote_address'),
                'mob_type',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table ::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'default' => NULL,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' => 'Mob Type'
                ]
            );
        $connection->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('sales_order_address'),
                'mob_type',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table ::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'default' => NULL,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' => 'Mob Type'
                ]
            );
        $installer->endSetup();
```

**Plugin**

```
use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor;

class MobPlugin
{
    public function afterProcess(LayoutProcessor $subject, $jsLayout) {
        $customAttributeCode = 'mob_type';
        $customField = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
                'id' => 'drop-down',
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.mob_type',
            'label' => 'Mob Type',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => ['required-entry' => true],
            'sortOrder' => 150,
            'id' => 'drop-down',
            'options' => [
                [
                    'value' => 'local',
                    'label' => 'Local',
                ],
                [
                    'value' => 'vip',
                    'label' => 'VIP',
                ]
            ]
        ];

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$customAttributeCode] = $customField;

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

[image]

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="save_custom_field" type="Namespace\CustomModule\Plugin\Checkout\SaveAddressInformation" />
    </type>

</config>
```

**SaveAddressInformation.php**

```
class SaveAddressInformation
{
    protected $quoteRepository;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
     */
    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
        $shippingAddress = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddressExtensionAttributes = $shippingAddress->getExtensionAttributes();
    if ($shippingAddressExtensionAttributes) {
        $customField = $shippingAddressExtensionAttributes->getMobType();
        $shippingAddress->setMobType($customField);
    }

    }
}
```

[image]
[Refe Extension](https://github.com/arvindporiya/poriyabrother)

**Above plugin is working fine and save values in the quote_address table. I want to display custom attribute in order view page and email template also.anyone have an idea what's wrong with the code. Thanks in advance**

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195468/how-to-get-and-set-data-in-checkout-shipping-address-magento-2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: your example not work in magento2.2.3

Comment: share your issue so I can check it

Comment: how can i get email id when guest checkout is enable

Comment: quote and order object return it

Comment: I got it working also with module from GitHub after adding variable in: Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Address Templates But it is only working when editing address from admin. When I click edit billing/shipping address my custom field is not populated with additional value that I insert while creating Customer. Does anybody have idea how should I do that?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136410)

Comment: Have you got the solution? If yes please share it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Navigate to System Configuration

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Address Templates
```

From Address Templates, Find HTML section, untick checkbox system value, add following code. you may change an attribute code if need.

For the email template, same address format [HTML Address format] will work.

```
{{depend mob_type}}Mob_Type: {{var mob_type}}{{/depend}}
```

Run `php bin/magento cache:clean` if not shows.

An attribute will show at the order view page and order email also.

above is displayed in both address but if you want only show in shipping then you need to put only SMS value in shipping address table (`sales_order_address and quote_address`) not billing it's working fine. Enjoy

**Table view -**

[image]

**Result -**

[image]

Comment: how can I save only in shipping address?

Comment: you need to add the event. or this one may be usefull - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138902/magento-2-save-custom-shipping-address-fields-to-quote-address-table

Comment: Actually it not works for my case, i don't understand how a variable can refer to extension attrbute which already was saved in quote_address & sales_order_address table. Seems i need to override the two info.phtml template

Comment: @hkguile can you please post your solution?

Comment: Just in case anyone having issues dispkaying value in sales order view: Plugin works well, but solution to display it in admin order page did not worked for me, so I added sales/order/view/info.phtml in my Vendor/Module folder and added <?php $add = $order->getShippingAddress();echo "Mob Type: ".$add->getMobType()?> it display the value in sales order page

Comment: Hi, i got same issue, but i want show my custom attribute on frontend - on details.html file but the currentBillingAddress haven't extensionAttributes data, any way do it?

Answer (score 5):

Try with my approach. Taking into consideration module as described in the question.

1. Used the same module showing in the question. no change
2. Installed reference extension which you are referring (SMS extension)

Navigate to System Configuration

> Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration ->
>   Address Templates

From Address Templates, Find HTML section, untick checkbox system value, add following code. you may change an attribute code if need.

For email template, same address format [HTML Address format] will work.

```
{{depend mob_type}}Mob_Type: {{var mob_type}}{{/depend}}
```

[image]

may be required to clear cache.

Run `php bin/magento cache:clean` if not shows

An attribute will show at the order view page and order email also.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. how we manage display only in shipping address area?

Comment: you may have to create more system configuration, for shipping address only as `html_for_shipping`.

`Magento/sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml`, find below line
`$block->getFormattedAddress( $order->getShippingAddress() );`
change to 
`$block->getFormattedShippingAddress( $order->getShippingAddress() );`
In `info.php` file, you may create new method only for shipping address formatting.
You can change parameter of format method 'html' to 'html_for_shipping', where 'html_for_shipping' will be your new system configuration value for shipping address format.

Comment: suddenly it's not working. not display me above SMS details in order. any idea?

Comment: I tried this @sandip..But it does not get displayed....Please help me

Comment: not working for me, value saved in db table but not showing in backend

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 3):

If the attribute is saved correctly you need to add the attribute to address templates. These can be found in

> Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration ->
>   Address Templates

You can add at the end something like:

```
{{depend mob_type}}, Mob. Type: {{var mob_type}}{{/depend}}
```

Depending on the template type, you can use `<br/>` to create new lines.

Comment: I want to display only shipping address and how I can manage also on order view page?

Comment: These templates are used everywhere. Frontend, backend, pdf, emails ... If the attribute is saved only in shipping address then it will only display there

Comment: ok, let me check it

Comment: Not working. not display anywhere. -http://nimb.ws/9cnpHW

Comment: Hi @Langley Thanks for the answer, iam getting this only in billing address not displaying it in shipping address, i want to display it in both places.

Answer (score 2):

I would do that like this: add it to the `quote` and `sales_order`and work the data from there use the following code ( also try using UpgradeSchema scripts if you need to update existing DB table, InstallSchema should be used for new DB tables )

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $quoteAddressTable = 'quote';
        $orderTable = 'sales_order';

        //Quote address table
        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($quoteAddressTable),
                'mob_type',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Mob type'
                ]
            );
        //Order address table
        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($orderTable),
                'mob_type',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Mob type'

                ]
            );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Create a mixin js as follows:

in `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information': {
                '<YourNamespace_YourModule>/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

the `set-shipping-information-mixin.js`

```
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setShippingInformationAction) {

        return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction) {
            var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();
            if (shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {};
            }

            shippingAddress['extension_attributes']['custom_field'] = shippingAddress.customAttributes['custom_field'];
            // pass execution to original action ('Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information')
            return originalAction();
        });
    };
});
```

Also you should have a `extension_attributes.xml` in `Your_Module/etc/` with following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="custom_field" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

make changes where needed ( attribute code, type, etc. this will add your custom attribute to the shipping information

Comment: but how to save this field data in the table can you please share code? thanks

Comment: can you show me how you defined your plugin in the `di.xml` file?

Comment: check I updated save field code and working fine but how to display in order shipping address area?

Comment: thanks for the update but look my above question. save things done but not display on the order view and email template. thanks

Comment: the fields there are show with the `getShippingAddress()` function that gets all the fields set to the address itself, thats why I added this code , it should add your attribute to the shipping address itself

Comment: you are right but not getting itself that's a problem.