# Magento 2 how to add extra fields for radio button option in checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, checkout-page

Give option in Address Information tab on checkout page

I want to add separate option after shipping Information on checkout page

1. Billing by weight
2. Billing by length

Radio buttons user can  select.

How I add this functionality?

Comment: Are you using Community edition or Enterprise Edition(Magento Commerce).

Comment: Community edition 2.1.7

Comment: I think this answer can help you : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216191/shipping-address-custom-attribute-value-not-display-in-address-box-in-magento2-2